# How can I give the same linux user ID for more than one applications?

Tags: android

I would like to give same linux user ID for more than one applications.
How can I give the same linux user ID for more than one applications.

thanks,
Venu.

Answer (score 1):

You should look here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid

Comment: Thanks LadaRaider.the link that You had given helped greatly.